# Python - Finding lowest position in an an 'array'

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

My goal is to move a 'monster' (`mX, mY`) in a 2d grid towards the player (`pX, pY`). The monster can move in 8 different directions.

I have working code for this, but I'm very new to Python. I have a strong inclination that my code is awful, and that there are faster ways to do it.

I do this by creating a 3 x 3 array around the monster's position (array slot 4), and filling it with the distance from that array position to the player. Then I check if any are lower than the monsters current distance, and if so, move the monster to it.

[image]

Here is my current code. Apologies if it makes you puke, I'm still learning the ropes.

```
# get the distance between the monster and player
dist = math.hypot(pX - mX, pY - mY)

if dist > 1.5 and dist < 10:

    # make an 'array' grid to store updated distances in
    goto = np.full((3, 3), 10, dtype=float)

    # if each position in the array passes a
    # collision check, add each new distance

    if collisionCheck(mID, (mX-1), (mY-1), mMap) == 0:
        goto[0][0] = round(math.hypot(pX - (mX-1), pY - (mY-1)), 1)

    if collisionCheck(mID, mX, (mY-1), mMap) == 0:
        goto[0][1] = round(math.hypot(pX - mX, pY - (mY-1)), 1)

    if collisionCheck(mID, (mX+1), (mY-1), mMap) == 0:
        goto[0][2] = round(math.hypot(pX - (mX+1), pY - (mY-1)), 1)

    if main.collisionCheck(mID, (mX-1), mY, mMap) == 0:
        goto[1][0] = round(math.hypot(pX - (mX-1), pY - mY), 1)

    # goto[1][1] is skipped since that is the monsters current position

    if collisionCheck(mID, (mX+1), mY, mMap) == 0:
        goto[1][2] = round(math.hypot(pX - (mX+1), pY - mY), 1)

    if collisionCheck(mID, (mX-1), (mY+1), mMap) == 0:
        goto[2][0] = round(math.hypot(pX - (mX-1), pY - (mY+1)), 1)

    if collisionCheck(mID, mX, (mY+1), mMap) == 0:
        goto[2][1] = round(math.hypot(pX - mX, pY - (mY+1)), 1)

    if collisionCheck(mID, (mX+1), (mY+1), mMap) == 0:
        goto[2][2] = round(math.hypot(pX - (mX+1), pY - (mY+1)), 1)

    # get the lowest distance, and its key
    lowest = goto.min()
    lowestKey = goto.argmin()

    # if the lowest distance is lower than monsters current position, move

    if lowest < dist:
            if lowestKey == 0: 
                    newX = mX - 1
                    newY = mY - 1

            if lowestKey == 1:
                    newY = mY - 1

            if lowestKey == 2: 
                    newX = mX + 1
                    newY = mY - 1

            if lowestKey == 3: 
                    newX = mX - 1

            if lowestKey == 5: 
                    newX = mX + 1

            if lowestKey == 6: 
                    newY = mY + 1
                    newX = mX - 1

            if lowestKey == 7:
                    newY = mY + 1

            if lowestKey == 8: 
                    newX = mX + 1
                    newY = mY + 1
```

What is the cleanest, simplest, and fastest way to do what I'm doing? This is going to loop through many monsters at once!

---

EDIT: Added `collisionCheck()`:

```
def collisionCheck(mobID, newX, newY, mapName):
    blocked = 0
    if mobs.mobPos_arr[mapName][newX,newY] > -1:
        blocked = 1

    if mapCollision_arr[mapName][newX,newY] > 0:
        blocked = 1

    return int(blocked)
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to move this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)? In before: I'm ready to participate. "Cleanest, simplest and fastest way" - itself is eligible question but it's does not looks a problem statement IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array broadcasting to compute the potential new positions at once:

```
delta = np.arange(-1, 2)
move = np.stack([np.repeat(delta, 3), np.tile(delta, 3)], axis=1)

# Assuming that m_pos.shape is (N: number of monsters, 2).
options = m_pos[:, None, :] + move  # Shape (N, 9, 2).

# Collision check.
zip_pos = tuple(zip(*options.reshape(-1, 2)))
check_1 = mobs.mobPos_arr[mapName][zip_pos] > -1
check_2 = mapCollision_arr[mapName][zip_pos] > 0
valid = ~(check_1 | check_2).reshape(-1, 9)

# Now compute distance.
distance = np.linalg.norm(p_pos - options, axis=-1)

# Incorporate whether moves are valid.
valid_distance = np.where(valid, distance, np.inf)

# Select the best move (the one with smallest valid distance).
best = np.argmin(valid_distance, axis=-1)

# Select new positions from the options, based on best move estimation.
new_pos = options[np.arange(len(options)), best]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very condensed. Any way I could work the collisionCheck() into that? The positions I can move to need to be ran through that first

Comment: @user1022585 That really depends on the details of `collisionCheck` (whether it can be vectorized or not). Can you provide the implementation?